# Hadoop could not work with lxc and ubuntu16.04

Tags: java, hadoop, lxc, ubuntu-16.04

When I run hadoop-2.6.0 on lxc container.
Host PC's OS is ubuntu 16.04 and container's OS also ubuntu 16.04.

Following lines are errors.

Anyone who can run hadoop on lxc(ubuntu16.04)?

Following lines are error code runnning hadoop.

```
hadoop@master:/tmp$ ./restart-hadoop-dfs.sh
+ stop-dfs.sh
Stopping namenodes on [master]
master: stopping namenode
cluster-slave02: no datanode to stop
master: stopping datanode
cluster01-slave04: no datanode to stop
cluster01-slave03: no datanode to stop
cluster-slave01: no datanode to stop
Stopping secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: stopping secondarynamenode
+ stop-yarn.sh
stopping yarn daemons
stopping resourcemanager
cluster-slave02: stopping nodemanager
master: stopping nodemanager
cluster-slave01: stopping nodemanager
cluster01-slave04: stopping nodemanager
cluster01-slave03: stopping nodemanager
master: nodemanager did not stop gracefully after 5 seconds: killing with kill -9
no proxyserver to stop
+ sudo rm -rf /var/hadoop/hdfs/datanode /var/hadoop/hdfs/namenode
+ hdfs namenode -format
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = master/157.82.3.142
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.6.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r e3496499ecb8d220fba99dc5ed4c99c8f9e33bb1; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2014-11-13T21:10Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_91
************************************************************/
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
Formatting using clusterid: CID-dff9fad1-84cc-448d-a135-77ab870488a6
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: No KeyProvider found.
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=true
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec is set to 000:00:00:00.000
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: The block deletion will start around 2016 Jul 01 09:33:58
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries

16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 2
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: shouldCheckForEnoughRacks  = false
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = hadoop (auth:SIMPLE)
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory 889 MB = 8.9 MB
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 889 MB = 2.2 MB
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.NNConf: ACLs enabled? false
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.NNConf: XAttrs enabled? true
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.NNConf: Maximum size of an xattr: 16384
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-275974701-157.82.3.142-1467365638786
16/07/01 09:33:58 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /var/hadoop/hdfs/namenode has been successfully formatted.
16/07/01 09:33:59 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
16/07/01 09:33:59 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
16/07/01 09:33:59 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at master/157.82.3.142
************************************************************/
+ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [master]
master: starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-master.out
cluster-slave02: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-cluster-slave02.out
cluster-slave01: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-cluster-slave01.out
cluster01-slave03: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-cluster01-slave03.out
master: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-master.out
cluster01-slave04: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-cluster01-slave04.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-master.out
+ start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-master.out
cluster-slave01: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-cluster-slave01.out
cluster01-slave03: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-cluster01-slave03.out
cluster01-slave04: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-cluster01-slave04.out
cluster-slave02: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-cluster-slave02.out
master: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-master.out
+ hadoop jar /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar pi 3 3
Number of Maps  = 3
Samples per Map = 3
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Wrote input for Map #2
Starting Job
16/07/01 09:34:24 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/157.82.3.142:8032
16/07/01 09:34:25 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
16/07/01 09:34:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:3
16/07/01 09:34:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1467365657240_0001
16/07/01 09:34:25 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1467365657240_0001
16/07/01 09:34:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1467365657240_0001/
16/07/01 09:34:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1467365657240_0001
16/07/01 09:34:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/157.82.3.142:38101. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/07/01 09:34:36 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/157.82.3.142:38101. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/07/01 09:34:37 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/157.82.3.142:38101. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/07/01 09:34:40 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/157.82.3.142:36772. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/07/01 09:34:41 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/157.82.3.142:36772. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/07/01 09:34:42 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/157.82.3.142:36772. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/07/01 09:34:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1467365657240_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/07/01 09:34:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/07/01 09:34:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1467365657240_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1467365657240_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1467365657240_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 255
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://master:8088/proxy/application_1467365657240_0001/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1467365657240_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 255
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=255:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 255
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
16/07/01 09:34:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
Job Finished in 17.93 seconds
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/user/hadoop/QuasiMonteCarlo_1467365661919_1251182664/out/reduce-out
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1750)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1774)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.estimatePi(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:314)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.run(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.main(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:363)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: Errors are missing...

Comment: where are the errors? .. go through this and edit accordingly http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask